# Create a batch file to add a beginning and end to text file lines

Tags: command-line, batch

Can anyone show me how to create a batch file to add a beginning and end to each line of a text file?

I have a large list and it would take endless time to add this to beginning and end.

Even a batch file just to add the end

Example if the words in a list is:

```
sample
test
placeholder
```

What I need to happen is for each item to do this:

```
<option value="sample">sample</option>
<option value="test">test</option>
<option value="placeholder">placeholder</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a batch file? Is powershell an option?  Here is the entire powershell command you would need.

```
Get-Content filename | % { "<option value=`"$_`">$_</option>"}
```

A text editor with a search and replace that supports regular expression and backreferences would also make this easy.  You would search for this `^(.*)$`, and replace it with `<option value="$1">$1</option>` in Sublime, or Notepad++.